# CSS: absolute positioning in different browsers

Tags: css, position, absolute

Why is this getting different positions on different browsers?

```
{
    position: absolute;
    left:332px;
    top: 210px;
    width: 293px;
    height: 215px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #143f72;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

In IE it goes to the left like 100px compared to Firefox, and in Chrome it goes like 100px to the right relative to FF... Why?

Edit: The html is just `<div id="container"><div id="the_css_above_div"></div></div>`

`#container` has the following css:

```
#container{
    float:left;
    width: 632px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: need html code in order to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Just checked it on IE8, FF and Chrome. Doesn't seem to be any different on any of them. Check http://jsfiddle.net/EQn2E . Would need to see other code to see if there is a problem.

Comment: the html is just <div id="that_css_id"></div>

Comment: Note that `position: absolute` is relative to the first parent with a `position` other than the default. Maybe some browsers consider a `float` different from default and other browsers do not?

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of this, make a complete test case using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/). Or, provide a live link to your page.

Comment: Adding `position: relative` to the container might fix the issues you're experiencing, but that's just a wild guess. Recommend providing a link to a test page like @thirtydot and @anothershrubery suggested. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it to work... The parent div needs to have `position:relative` in it's CSS declaration. If anyone comes across this problem check your parent div :)

Comment: Or provide people trying to help with more info?

Comment: I believe it is true not just for IE... blocks are positioned absolutely in relationship to the parent that has position attribute set to relative or absolute, or in relationship to the window if no parent has position defined...

Comment: i was JUST about to post something about this....problem ive been having and as SOON as i saw your "got it to work" im like, WTF I KNOW THIS!!!! lol......thanks. +1

Comment: Thanks, luqita.  I would never have figured this out without your post.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div has to have `position:relative;`. Otherwise your `position:absolute;` will position from all page. If parent div has relative positioning absolute div positions itself based on his parent.